# How can add imageview in exactly position android

Tags: android

Can you tell me, how can I add imageview in exactly position like in that frame. Is that possible? Or is there any way to do something like this. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: then you can use canvas concept

Comment: make an parent layout like linear or relative with some padding and background as customized image,in that add imageview and load the image.

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me more specifically.

Comment: @Nithin but when we use different devices. I think that image view is not in the same position.

Comment: make gravity as center in linear layout and give match parent for width and height in imageview.Try setting these combinations and make some research.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. The image link you shared, it looks like you need a collage view.
You can try this public repository: https://github.com/thuytrinh/android-collage-views